# Diffie Hellman generating a result in a range

Tags: cryptography

I'm using the diffie-hellman key exchange method to securely generate a key for use with the AES cipher (the result will be hashed to make in the ideal length). Assuming the exponent is a prime of length 2^2048 bits, how can i calculate the size of the base and the modulus if i want the decimal result to be of a length in between (2^6)^32 and (2^6)^40 (i.e. a base64 string of length equal to or greater than 32 and less than or equal to 40 characters). The base i want to use is within the range 3

I'm new to Diffie-Hellman exchanges, are there any restrictions on the modulus, the base or the exponents that i should be aware of?

Is there an equation i can use to derive the ideal pair lengths, or do i have to pre calculate it and store it in an array.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking about.

For Diffie-Hellman you choose a [safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) or [strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime) prime *`p`* between `2^2047` and `2^2048-1` in your case, then choose an element `0 < g < p-1` such that `g^(p-1) mod *p*=1` but `g^x mod p≠1` for all `0 < x < p-1` . *`p`* and *`g`* are constant parameters for your implementation. The size of `g` does not matter for the scheme. Now for a key exchange you sample `0 < a,b < p-1` uniformly and random, exchange `g^a mod p` and `g^b mod p`, and calculate `g^ab mod p`. Because of the random choice of `a` and `b` the result `g^ab mod p` is also random with `0 < (g^ab mod p) < p-1`.

As you have already noticed you can then hash `g^ab mod p` to generate a short key (256 bit with sha256 for example).